# Is the Alexandria, Va. "Republican shooting" the first mass shooting of its kind in the USA?

Tags: united-states, political-history, political-party

If you are unaware, [Republican members and lawmakers of the United States were recently the target of a mass shooting in Alexandria, Virginia.](https://www.yahoo.com/news/shooting-gop-baseball-practice-scalise-shot-120338383.html) It seems that the gunman's target was specifically their political affiliation: he was hoping to kill Republicans.

I find myself noting this as a very strange event, despite the uneasy reality that mass shootings are nearly a monthly event now. Mass murderers of the past seem to have targeted by race, sexual orientation, religion, or government in general (e.g. Timothy McVeigh). There have been, of course, just plain old crazy mass killings with no particular target.

Is this the first time in U.S. history that a mass shooting/killing targeted political affiliation? I would suspect that some of this happened during the Civil War, but that was a war, a very different thing. So outside of military organized action, has there ever been a mass shooting/killing in the United States that targeted a political party?

Comment: How does this qualify as a 'mass killing'?

Comment: @user I suppose in the strict sense, it's not. I think none dead. But the intent to kill many is clear. He's just a bad shot. I will edit to "shooting".

Comment: Perhaps before the Civil War, in the Bleeding Kansas period?

Comment: There were several incidents during the Bleeding Kansas period when people were killed for being pro-slavery or anti-slavery, i.e., Democrat or Republican. For instance John Brown's [Pottawatomie Massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pottawatomie_massacre). I guess this particular incident doesn't count, since you changed "killing" to "shooting"; Brown's men used swords.

Comment: How do we know that the shooter was specifically targeting Republicans, rather than a generic event with people?

Comment: Not only wasn't this the first political party mass shooting, it wasn't the first one this decade. Not that anyone should be surprised. It wasn't even the only mass shooting *yesterday*. We averaged slightly over 1 a day last year, and have had more already than we had at this time last year. With those sheer numbers, just about every motivation imaginable must be hit on eventually.

Comment: Also, without shootings, the [1919 campaign of anarchist bombings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1919_United_States_anarchist_bombings) and (if we use the "political affiliation" instead of "political party" criteria) the [violence against Civil Rights movement in the 60s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Civil_Rights_Movement_(1954%E2%80%931968)), more specifically [the murder of three activists in Mississippi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murders_of_Chaney,_Goodman,_and_Schwerner)

Comment: @FelixGoldberg For example the shooter was explicitly asking directions and checked if those are the republicans.

Comment: @Feliz I believe a few witness reports have him asking "Are you Republicans?"

Comment: @fredsbend - What I'd heard this morning (on NPR morning edition I believe) was that somebody had stopped by and asked that question, but they didn't know if it was the shooter or not. From what I saw, they were wearing red uniforms with the word "Republicans" on them, so either way it would have been a pretty unnessecary question.

Comment: This shooting, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1954_United_States_Capitol_shooting_incident in the House of Representatives 63 years ago, seems to have targeted Dems and Republican's equally...

Comment: I can no longer find the references, but there was an episode in Philadelphia c. 1870 where a Democrat Marching Club did a tour of the city and when they got in front of the Republican Club (possibly on 5th street), a group Republicans (possibly the Republican Invincibles) filed out of their club, formed a line and opened fire on a the crowd of marchers and onlookers. Killed a number of people, including police officers. There was a London news item that curiously, inverted the perpetrators and victims.

Answer (score 12):

An earlier mass killing against a political affiliation is the [Coushatta massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coushatta_massacre) in 1874. Members of the [White League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_League), a white supremacist organisation composed of white Southern Democrats, assassinated six white Republicans and five to 20 freedmen who were witnesses. Their goal was to overturn Republican rule and install Democrats in their place.

Comment: Wow! That definitely fits. I'm surprised there wasn't retaliation. And I thought these were scary times now.

Answer (score 2):

The [2011 Tucson shooting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_Tucson_shooting) also seems to be such a case. The shooting took place at a constituent meeting held by Democratic Representative Gabrielle Giffords. While the [shooter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jared_Lee_Loughner) was insane his specific form of insanity included some sort of political mania.

Comment: Upvoted (because it was the first thing that entered my head). But this really needs to be expanded to be a proper answer.